# Counting voucher value total since the beginning of the month

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table called "vouchers" it contains fields named "voucher_value" and "redeemed_at". redeemed_at is in Unix timestamp format (generated by PHP time() function).

So I need get the total of voucher_value since the beginning of the month.

What's the SQL code for that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like:

```
SELECT SUM(voucher_value)
  FROM vouchers
 WHERE MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(redeemed_at)) = MONTH(CURDATE())
   AND YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(redeemed_at)) = YEAR(CURDATE())
```

perhaps

Comment: But maybe filter out data from different years? And also, shouldn't you first FROM_UNIXTIME(redeemed_at)?

Answer (score 3):

I believe that you will find all that you need in the [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html) for date and time functions.

**EDIT**:

Mark's answer is perfectly good. If you are chasing last drop of performance, your column type is [timestamp](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/timestamp.html) (watch for zone and range limitations) and you have an index on it then:

```
SELECT SUM(voucher_value)
FROM vouchers
WHERE redeemed_at BETWEEN
      UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_ADD(LAST_DAY(DATE_SUB(NOW(), interval 1 month)), interval 1 day))
      AND
      UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(DATE_ADD(LAST_DAY(NOW()), interval 1 day), interval 1 second))
```

should be much faster (as it will not have to apply any transformations to `redeemed_at`. The expressions are big/complex (and not thoroughly tested and it is for sure possible to write them more simple/shorter), but what is important is that they are *constant* and evaluated only once per query. Replace `NOW()` with parameter to gain two things

- generalization (of course)
- ability to cache results (mysql will NOT cache any queries that involve `NOW()`)